# Show the activities from queue

Tags: android

I have two classes `AlarmService.class,ReminderActivity.class`. AlarmService class calls the ReminderActivity when current time is equal to alarm time. For example if i set alarm for 3.01, 3.02 , 3.03 , 3.04 PM. I gets first ReminderActivity at 3.01 PM . Problem is that 3.02 PM ReminderActivity comes over the existing one , when i working on ReminderActivity which is comes at 3.01 PM. I need to display 3.02PM ReminderActivity after i completeing 3.01PM. 3.03PM
ReminderActivity displays after i completing 3.02PM and so on. How to achieve this? Help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the code you use to start the activity

Comment: if (time_.equalsIgnoreCase(alarm_time)) {
          Intent i1 = new Intent(
            AlarmService.this,
            ReminderActivity.class);
          Bundle b = new Bundle();
          b.putString("id", split[4]);
          b.putString("retrun_tag",
            "AlarmService");
          i1.putExtras(b);
          i1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          AlarmService.this.startActivity(i1);

Comment: You should try other flags like Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, and maybe try to manage a singleton of your ReminderActivity with a static method like getInstance

Answer (score 0):

Make the

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

in the manifest. This will ensure that only one instance of ReminderAcitivity is created. Now to implement how it handles 3:01, 3:02 and so on, you define the onNewIntent() function in your activity.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

If the activity is launched for first time from the alarm service save a boolean to a sharedpreferences property.

If this value is true then for the next alarm event you can:

- On the AlarmService save to a SQLite database the data. If the current activity is done (user presses a button like Done ,OK, ...) you can start same activity again loading it with new data.
- Send an intent to a broadcastreceiver registere on ReminderActivity, sharing the same action. The activity generates a dialog asking to user what to do.
- You generate a notification from the AlarmService.

If I were you I would use notifications and user can decide wich one to launch.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 ways of doing this:

**A.**
According to [Activity launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode), you could use set `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`. That's the easy case when you don't need to worry about how many stacks the app contains. Just don't forget to add the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` from service.

**B.** 
If the number of stacks is an issue, then you could do the following:
in ReminderActivity register an ordered broadcast with a higher priority than default. Register it in onCreate and deregister it in onDestroy(). Register another broadcast receiver in Manifest.xml (let's call it `MyOrderedReceiver`) with default priority that should only create above activity. Then when alarm is triggered, from service you will send an ordered broadcast: `sendOrderedBroadcast(new Intent("myAction"));`

If the activity is already created, then it will process the intent first in its receiver and it will abort the intent so that `MyOrderedReceiver` will not process the intent sent from `AlarmService`. If the activity is not on the stack, then MyOrderedReceiver will process the intent by starting ReminderActivity.

In case you find option B useful and you need more, I can post more implementation details on this.